# maven-scala-plugin giving pom file error

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm testing java code using scala and maven. The maven-scala-plugin is returning a pom file error in Eclipse. Here is my pom snippet :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is the error :

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:testCompile 
 (execution: scala-test-compile, phase: test-compile)
```

Have I configured the pom correctly ?

The scala tests are running correctly, in that they are all passing. Perhaps this is a Maven bug ?

When I view maven properties for the project the lifecycle mappings are not available : 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a Maven bug. [This page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#lifecycle_mapping_metadata_provided_by_maven_plugin) describes why the message is shown and how to deal with it.

After pressing Ctrl+1 over the problem Eclipse should suggest two quick fixes:

1. Discover new m2e connectors. Try this first, if it finds a connector restart Eclipse and rebuild the project, the problem should go away.
2. Permanently mark goal as ignored. It will add some code in `pom.xml` which means the goal won't be run on builds within Eclipse, only from command line. You can also replace `<ignore>` in the added part with `<execute>` to run the goal in Eclipse as well.

Comment: From reading the doc it seems "execution: scala-test-compile, phase: test-compile" does not have a lifecycle mapping to any of the mapping metadata sources. So it seems I can just ignore the error. Is this correct ? Please see question edit

Comment: Neither of these suggestions are satisfactory --- the first does not find a connector; the second leads to your scala files not being built in Eclipse.

Comment: @JoshHansen "You can also replace <ignore> in the added part with <execute> to run the goal in Eclipse as well."

Comment: @JoshHansen Also see user2635460's answer, there is a connector now.

Answer (score 15):

You should instal m2eclipse-connector from this update site: http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site

Check this documentation:

http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/index.html

Comment: Installing the right connector is better then ignoring the goal. That avoids the Maven build giving different results from the Eclipse build.

Answer (score 1):

Post installation of m2e plugin (Maven Integration for Scala IDE) in eclipse,  it worked well.